# How to prevent OleDbDataReader.ExecuteReader from auto-appending integers to duplicate column values

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, datareader

I'm trying to import data from an Excel (xls) spreadsheet. I need to throw an error if duplicate values appear in the header row. I'm using an OleDbDataReader to ingest the worksheet data. The problem I'm having is that .Net is appending a unique integer to the end of the duplicate columns so that all of the values are unique.

The header values will be be unknown at runtime. If duplicate header values are found, processing of the file should be stopped.

For example, a spreadsheet with the following headers:
Make, Model, Year, Make
Will appear as:
Make, Model, Year, Make1

Here is some code:

```
           string selectString = "Select * from $Sheet1";
           xlConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
           OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectString, xlConnection); 
           OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < reader.FieldCount; fieldIndex++)
                {
                    string columnValue = reader.GetName(fieldIndex);
                }
            }
```

GetName returns Make, Model, Year, Make1

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using:

```
  string selectString = "Select Make, Model, Year from $Sheet1";
```

instead of:

```
  string selectString = "Select * from $Sheet1";
```

Comment: Very close to what my answer was going to be.  The best way to ensure the runtime doesn't append numbers to prevent duplicate column names (which would really throw things off) is to explicitly set the column names you want returned in the SQL using the AS keyword.  +1.

Comment: The column names won't be known at runtime. The import code that we're using allows the user to import any file with up to 255 columns in the spreadsheet.

Comment: If there are duplicate columns, would you still want to continue processing with the file?

Comment: You might want to loop over the DataReaders fields to create the column list (for the SQL) dynamically - you will get a chance to ignore (if you choose to) columns which are similar (that is those with columnnames appended with 1 to an already existing column).

Comment: Arun - No, if duplicates are found, the file should not be processed

Comment: have you found a proper way to do this Brian? I'm going through the same crisis and in my case I don't know what the columns might be but just need to give and error if duplicates are found.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same requirement and faced the same challenge.

I solved it by modifying the connection string to set HDR=NO. Then selected the first row and looped through the values in each column to check for uniqueness. If I found a match I threw DuplicatNameException to be consistent with DataTable.

Hope this helps.